# How do I communicate between two camel context using camel "direct-vm"?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using direct-vm to communicate between two camel contexts running in same JVM. But it is not working, my producer keeps on looking for consumer :( Am I missing anything here. Any help is appreciated thanks :)

This is my Producer, sending data from files in a folder to endpoint

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class OrderRouter {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
   // create CamelContext
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

// add our route to the CamelContext
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() {

        from("file:src/data?noop=true").to("direct-vm:pipeRequestDR91");

        }
    });

    // start the route and let it do its work
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    // stop the CamelContext
    context.stop();
    } 
}
```

This is my Consumer polling on endpoint.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor; 
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {

            from("direct-vm:pipeRequestDR91").process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Reached here");
                    System.out.println("Received XML order: "
                            + exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));
                    String strBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                    System.out.println(strBody);
                }
            });

        }
    });

    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(100000);
    }
}
```

This is Error :

```
    Message History

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [file://src/data?noop=true                                                     ] [         5]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [direct-vm:pipeRequestDR91                                                     ] [         0]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-LP0G0085-56374-1502833874430-0-418
    ExchangePattern     InOnly
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-LP0G0085-56374-1502833874430-0-417, CamelFileAbsolute=false, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Prashant\camelinaction-master\chapter2\cbr\src\data\message2.csv, CamelFileContentType=application/vnd.ms-excel, CamelFileLastModified=1436197636000, CamelFileLength=53, CamelFileName=message2.csv, CamelFileNameConsumed=message2.csv, CamelFileNameOnly=message2.csv, CamelFileParent=src\data, CamelFilePath=src\data\message2.csv, CamelFileRelativePath=message2.csv, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
    BodyType            org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile
    Body                [Body is file based: GenericFile[message2.csv]]
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct-vm://pipeRequestDR91]. Exchange[message2.csv]
    at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProducer.process(DirectVmProducer.java:51)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:435)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_71]
[1) thread #0 - file://src/data] GenericFileOnCompletion        WARN  Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@281eff for file: GenericFile[message3.csl]
[1) thread #0 - file://src/data] DefaultErrorHandler
```

Comment: And you are sure the consumer is alive when the producer wants to send? Why not ensure your routes are alive "forever"?

Comment: My consumer stays alive for 100 secs and producer still keep on looking for it. While it runs and takes less than a sec when I use same camel-context.
How am I testing ? I am running both the applications one by one on eclipse.

Comment: Do I have to have them running in OSGI ? Is OSGI a constraint for direct-vm ?

Comment: One by one is not the same as in the same vm

Comment: You don't need OSGI, look at the Camel documentation. it says how to keep your camel context to run forever. Most likely your consumer is not available when your producer wants to send. OSGI and spring boot is more for deployment and management and other admin related tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an minimal example (but Thread.Sleep is just a quick way to show what means two contexts in the same jvm without osgi/spring etc.):

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext first = new DefaultCamelContext();
        first.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer:start").to("direct-vm:test");
            }
        });

        CamelContext second = new DefaultCamelContext();
        second.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct-vm:test").log("Message received");
            }
        });

        first.start();
        second.start();

        Thread.sleep(100000);
    }
}
```

Actually, as I see the real requirement is to communicate between different camel contexts in different applications so JVM will be different. The quickest way to do that similar to "direct" or "direct-vm" is to use camel-netty4 and option "transferExchange" set to "true" (http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html). Here is an example which contains two separate applications that communicating using this way:

App1.java

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class App1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext first = new DefaultCamelContext();
        first.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer:start").to("netty4:tcp://127.0.0.1:9999?transferExchange=true");
            }
        });

        first.start();
        Thread.sleep(100000);
    }
}
```

App2.java

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class App2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext second = new DefaultCamelContext();
        second.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("netty4:tcp://127.0.0.1:9999?transferExchange=true").log("Message received");
            }
        });

        second.start();

        Thread.sleep(100000);
    }
}
```

By changing IP address it will be possible to run applications on different machines etc.

Comment: Thanks this works fine for me too, but When I am trying same in two different maven projects as I have shown in example above, it does not work.

Comment: Sure it will not work as when you running them from ide or cli each one has it's own jvm

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even I was doubting it, Is there a way I can achieve this ?

Comment: If you really need to communicate between different applications where each one has its own camel context then you need to use some sort of TCP communication like netty (simplest way probably). I will update my answer and add corresponded examples

Answer (score 0):

Keep your consumer running forever as @Souciance Eqdam Rashti has mentioned.
You can refer below example from camel documentation to keep running camel context forever

> http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: So I tried that too, now my consumer is running forever, my producer still keeps looking for it, I think I might be missing something else. Do you have a working example that you can share with me please, Thanks Murli!

Answer (score 0):

short answer is : routes cannot communicate through `direct-vm` when contexts are in different JVMs. Period.

They will if they run in the same JVM - as example two WAR/EAR files running in some Java EE containers like JBoss, Weblogic, Tomcat etc.
Or when there is a main method in application which starts both contexts.
It can be done in different threads as example.

Comment: Yeah totally agree with you and I tried that where I started a route from other application in the main application. Since it was started in same JVM it was working fine for me. Thanks for you response Arjan